# Argument type in templated function forced to a given type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The following runs fine:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/**
 * Simply print the value of the argument and adapt the 
 * statement based on its type. 
 */
template<typename T>
int function(T value){

    if(std::is_same<T,double>() || std::is_same<T,float>()){
        std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(std::is_same<T,std::string>()){
        std::cout << value << ", type is string" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(std::is_same<T,char*>() || std::is_same<T,const char*>()){
        std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 
    }
}

int main(){
    function<double>(1.2345); 
    function<std::string>("Hello World");
    const char* sentence = "Hello World"; function<const char*>(sentence);
    return 0; 
}
```

Since this runs without any issue, I tried changing the following line:

```cpp
std::cout << value << ", type is string" << std::endl;
```

to

```cpp
std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl;
```

However this does not compile. It is like if the type of `value` was defined when compiling the `.c_str()` call. However, I would have expected the type of the `value` argument to only depend on the template argument `T`. Why isn't it compiling in this case?

Following error is generated:

```
In instantiation of ‘int function(T) [with T = double]’:
.cpp:321:25:   required from here
error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘value’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
   std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl;
                ~~~~~~^~~~~
In instantiation of ‘int function(T) [with T = const char*]’:
.cpp:323:70:   required from here
.cpp:306:22: error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘value’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
```

Comment: Why should it? You pass `const char*`, which has no `.c_str()` function. You also pass `double`, which again also fails this requirement

Comment: You are likely looking for [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if). The "normal" `if` checks its condition at runtime; all branches must compile even though only one is actually taken.

Comment: Just for completeness, both `std::string` and `const char*` should be handled. The problem really lies with the `std::string` case.

Comment: @Lala5th, could you please elaborate? My question is why shouldn't it compile? What am I missing?

Comment: @LoW Igor explains it in their comment very well

Comment: You're right, sorry, skipped his explanation by accident, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your original code, you are not actually using any members of `value`, so its type is fairly irrelevant to the body of the `if` statements.  You are simply relying on `operator<<` overloading to "do the right thing".

However, once you start accessing the members of `value`, its type becomes very relevant to your code.

For example, lets take your first test case, `double`.  The compiler will NOT instantiate the version of your function that you are expecting:

```cpp
int function<double>(double value){
    std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

It will INSTEAD instantiate this version of your function:

```cpp
int function<double>(double value){

    if(std::is_same<double,double>() || std::is_same<double,float>()){ //true
        std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(std::is_same<double,std::string>()){ // false
        std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl;
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(std::is_same<double,char*>() || std::is_same<double,const char*>()){ // false
        std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Your `std::string` and `const char*` test cases will instantiate similar versions, too.  NOT the ones you are expecting.

This is because your function is creating instances of `std::is_same` at runtime and invoking its `bool` conversion operator, so all of those `if`s are **runtime checks**, and so their branches must contain valid code at compile-time to be executed at runtime. No branches are able to be eliminated at compile-time. And since `double` and `const char*` do not have a `c_str()` member, you get the errors you are seeing.

Now, you might be tempted to avoid that runtime behavior by replacing `std::is_same<T,...>()` with either `std::is_same<T,...>::value` or `std::is_same_v<T,...>`, which are compile-time constants.  And you would be half-correct to do so:

```cpp
template<typename T>
int function(T value){

    if(std::is_same_v<T,double> || std::is_same_v<T,float>){
    //if(std::is_same<T,double>::value || std::is_same<T,float>::value){
        std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(std::is_same_v<T,std::string>){
    //else if(std::is_same<T,std::string>::value){
        std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl;
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(std::is_same_v<T,char*> || std::is_same_v<double,const char*>){
    //else if(std::is_same<T,char*>::value || std::is_same<double,const char*>::value){
        std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Which would simplify down to, for example `double`:

```cpp
int function<double>(double value){

    if(true){
        std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(false){
        std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl;
        return 0; 
    }
    else if(false){
        std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

However, the compiler will still need to *fully* evaluate the code inside each `if` branch, and so each branch still needs to contain valid code, even if the compiler will be able to optimize out any unused branches **after** evaluating their code.  And in this context, `value.c_str()` is still invalid code for types of `T` that don't have a `c_str()` member.

To solve this, you need to use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), which will perform **compile-time checks** and *eliminate unused branches **before** evaluating their code*, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
int function(T value){

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,double> || std::is_same_v<T,float>()){
        std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,std::string>){
        std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,char*> || std::is_same_v<T,const char*>){
        std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler will be able to instantiate your function as you are expecting:

```cpp
int function<double>(double value){ // and float
    std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}

int function<std::string>(std::string value){
    std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}

int function<const char*>(const char* value){
    std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}

template<typename T>
int function(T value){
    std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
    return -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) for suggesting the use of [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) and [@Lala5th](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10055166/lala5th) for highlighting his suggestion.

The function should look like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
int function(T value){
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T,double>() || std::is_same<T,float>()){
        std::cout << value << ", type is float" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T,std::string>()){
        std::cout << value.c_str() << ", type is string" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T,char*>() || std::is_same<T,const char*>()){
        std::cout << value << ", type is char*" << std::endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Unsupported data type" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should be using `std::is_same<T,...>::value`, or better `std::is_same_v<T,...>`, rather than `std::is_same<T,double>()`. The latter creates an object instance of `std::is_same` and invokes its `bool` conversion operator, which is unnecessary since the `value` member is a compile-time constant